# How to clear a form(s), when input changes?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

My example form:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Server)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Server, new { @class = "form-control", id = "serverTextbox" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Username, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control", id = "usersCombo" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Database)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Database, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control", id = "databaseCombo" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Company, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control", id = "companyCombo" })
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" id="LogOn" value="Log In" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
<div>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
</div>

}
```

So when a user changes their server entry (first input), I'm looking to implement an .change() event listener (i think), to clear the other dependant forms (drop down & input) without the use of an actual reset button.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: How about `$(':input').on('change',function(){$('form').reset()})` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options presented so far will also erase the server value, which I supose is not desirable.

A better option, not jQuery dependant, would probably be:

```
var serverInput = document.getElementById("serverTextbox");
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];

serverInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var temp = this.value;
    form.reset();
    this.value = temp;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use form reset like this

```
$('input .form-control').on('change',function()
{
    $("#form")[0].reset();        
})
```

You can also write your custom implementation which will explicitly reset the values like

```
function clearForms()
{
    JQuery(".form-control").attr('value',' ');
    //do this for all controls and call this function
}
```